# Slow Query Due to Multiple, JOIN-laden Subqueries

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm currently developing a LIMS. I need to retrieve information relating to lab samples which need to be prepped using a certain prep method. (I'm simplifying this quite a lot, so apologies for any mistakes.) The columns I need to produce in my query results are:

```
Sample number|
Container type|
List of ALL chain of custodies this sample appears on|
List of ALL analysis items this sample needs to be prepped for|
List of ALL prep methods this sample needs to go through
```

For example:

```
Sample 1|100g|101, 102, 103, 104|BTEX, TPH|Moisture Content, Pentane
Sample 2|200g|101, 103|BTEX, Atterberg Limits|Headspace, Moisture Content, Pentane
Sample 3|200g|101, 102, 104|Atterberg Limits|Headspace, Moisture Content
```

I have to retrieve the lists for the last three columns from three different tables. I'm currently using three different subqueries to do this:

```
SELECT
  lab_coc_samples.Sample_Number,
  lab_coc_samples.Container,
  (Subquery 1),
  (Subquery 2),
  (Subquery 3)
FROM  lab_coc_samples
JOIN  lab_coc                            ON lab_coc_samples.CoC_ID = lab_coc.Data_ID
JOIN  lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods ON lab_coc.Analysis_Item = lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods.Analysis_Code
WHERE lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods.Prep_Code = 1
```

Subquery 1: each sample will appear on several different chain of custodies, so my subquery for the first column is:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT lab_coc_samples.CoC_ID SEPARATOR ',')
FROM lab_coc_samples

WHERE lab_coc_samples.Sample_Code = s1.Sample_Code
GROUP BY lab_coc_samples.Sample_Code
```

Subquery 2: each chain of custody has one analysis item, but each sample will be linked to several analysis items because it appears on multiple CoCs:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT lab_analysis_items.Name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM lab_coc_samples

JOIN lab_coc            ON lab_coc.Data_ID = lab_coc_samples.CoC_ID
JOIN lab_analysis_items ON lab_analysis_items.Code = lab_coc.Analysis_Item

WHERE lab_coc_samples.Sample_Code = s1.Sample_Code
GROUP BY lab_coc_samples.Sample_Code
```

Subquery 3: Each analysis item is linked to multiple prep methods (so: multiple samples which are related to multiple analysis items which are related to multiple prep methods -- joy):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT lab_prep_methods.Name SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM lab_coc_samples

JOIN lab_coc                            ON lab_coc_samples.CoC_ID = lab_coc.Data_ID
JOIN lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods ON lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods.Analysis_Code = lab_coc.Analysis_Item
JOIN lab_prep_methods                   ON lab_prep_methods.Code = lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods.Prep_Code

WHERE lab_coc_samples.Sample_Code = s1.Sample_Code
GROUP BY lab_coc_samples.Sample_Code
```

There are thousands of samples in this database that need prepping, which makes this query very slow. How can I increase the efficiency of this query without modifying the structure of the database? Can I use joins somehow, even though I need information about ALL instances of the sample in each of the tables? Would joins even help?

Answer (score 0):

This should make it a bit better. You are practically repeating the outer query in the inner queries, but not anymore:

```
SELECT
  lab_coc_samples.Sample_Number,
  lab_coc_samples.Container,
  (Subquery 1),
  (Subquery 2),
  (Subquery 3)

FROM  lab_coc_samples

JOIN  lab_coc
  ON  lab_coc.Data_ID = lab_coc_samples.CoC_ID

JOIN  lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods
  ON  lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods.Analysis_Code = lab_coc.Analysis_Item
 AND  lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods.Prep_Code = 1

WHERE lab_coc_samples.Sample_Code = s1.Sample_Code

GROUP BY lab_coc_samples.Sample_Code
```

Subquery 1:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT lab_coc_samples.CoC_ID SEPARATOR ',')
```

Subquery 2:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT lab_analysis_items.Name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM  lab_analysis_items
WHERE lab_analysis_items.Code = lab_coc.Analysis_Item
```

Subquery 3:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT lab_prep_methods.Name SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM  lab_prep_methods
WHERE lab_prep_methods.Code = lab_analysis_items_to_prep_methods.Prep_Code
```

Comment: This is looking good. I'm trying to implement, but I think it only picks up the prep method stipulated in the filter query rather than every prep method that sample has been linked to. It also only seems to pick up one analysis item p/sample. CoC list works great, though.

Comment: I knew I f'd up something… :) Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I improved the query time myself by creating a nested table containing my list fields, and adding indexes to the JOIN fields in my queries. Most notably, adding an index to the VARCHAR 'Sample_Code' field sped things up by a few seconds.